# Magento 2.3.5 - Could we configure our installed module fields via Magento 2 CLI?

Tags: magento2, cli, magento2.3.5

Could we actually configure our installed module fields via Magento 2 CLI?

For example:

```
# typical way to enable a Magento 2 module, via Magento 2 CLI
bin/magento module:enable Acme_Acme

# can we do something like this?
bin/magento module:enable Acme_Acme --config=[password=1234]
```

Goal:
The goal is to make `bin/magento module:enable` a little dummy-proof, if some more than one 'required' configuration field is still null or empty.

When the module is enabled, with the empty 'required' configuration fields, the plugin causes Magento 2 site errors and so on.

Alternative solutions:
If going about the Magento 2 CLI is the wrong path towards a solution, what other solutions are available? Using the `di.xml` file? Programmatically "catch" for empty 'required' configuration fields?

FYI, Magento 2 casual here. Please feel free to share your thoughts, thank you.

Comment: You can set the depedency and validation on that fields on the configuration it self.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I see, I believe that's what I'm missing. I did a quick search on Magento 2 docs, with your suggestion and keywords. Are you referring to this example (I understand this is v2.4 docs)? (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/config-reference-systemxml.html#field-validation)

Comment: Yes, let me post one example so you get idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using your `system.xml` file like this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
       <section id="yoursectionid" sortOrder="150" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>YOUR LABLE</label>
            <tab>yourtab</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Extension::yourresourcename</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" sortOrder="10" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Your Extension Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="yourcustomfield" translate="label" sortOrder="20" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Your Custom Field Title</label>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="*/*/enable">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
             </group>
         </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you @DhirenVasoya for the example! Before your example, I was trying it out myself, trial-and-error. Yes, the `<validate>` element is all I needed actually, and you've also shown the `<depends>` element too, which gave me new ideas for the other fields' validations. Cheers, much appreciated!

Comment: Great, if answer upvote and mark as solutions, so it will help other in community as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, no problem. Your example above is "Accepted Answer". To upvote, I can't at this time, cause I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but my feedback has been recorded.